# How to print a four pages on one page?

Tags: macbook-pro, pdf, printing

I would like to print a PDF document, so that four pages of the docoument is printed on one A4 page. (It is 26 pages all in all, so I want to have 7 papers printed having four pages from the pdf on each and having two on the last one). How is it possible to set?

Answer (score 24):

You can do 4-up printing from most macOS applications in the standard print dialog.

1. Choose File menu > Print (Command-P)
2. If there's a Show Details button, click it. (If there's a Hide Details button instead, you're already in the right mode.)
3. Find the printer options pop-up menu somewhere in the print dialog. It's not labelled, but will generally have "Layout" or the current app's name selected. From that pop-up menu, choose Layout.
4. Underneath that, there'll be a "Pages per Sheet" pop-up menu. Choose "4" from that. It should look something like this:

[image]

5. Click Print.

Answer (score 0):

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro 10 one can do 4-up (and more) printing and PDF output in the **Print...** dialog itself. Using the Page Sizing and Handling options, choosing Multiple and accepting the default 2 by 2 pages per sheet setting. The thumbnail on the right shows 4 consecutive pages of a pdf document per page.

[image]