# Quick way to preview all pages in a PDF file

Tags: pdf, preview, keynote, quicklook, quicklook-plugin

Is there a quick way or software for *MacOS* that makes it easy to quickly preview all (or many) pages in a single PDF file. Optimally, it would preview a PDF with multiple pages, similar to how *Quick Look* [shows multiple files](https://www.cultofmac.com/194232/use-quick-look-with-multiple-files-impress-your-geeky-mac-friends-os-x-tips/).

Currently in *Quick Look*, I have to scroll through the pages (this does not give me the overview I would like). Alternatively, I'll have to;

1. Open PDF in Preview,
2. Open print dialog,
3. [Choose layout and select 16 pages per sheet](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285651/how-to-print-a-four-pages-on-one-page),
4. Save as a new PDF, and then
5. *Quick Look* or open the new PDF. Which gives something like this:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preview also has something called a "Contact Sheet" (similar to the contact sheets one printed for photos on a film).

Open the PDF in Preview and either press <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>, or go to the "**View**" menu and select "**Contact Sheet**".

Then zoom in or out to taste.